# Creating Hole in object using ThreeJS and Stencil method

Tags: three.js, stencil-buffer

I am trying to make a hole in a solid object(box) using stencil method in ThreeJS. I found few web pages and similar questions on the net in this regard but couldn't work them out. Specifically [This link](https://playground.babylonjs.com/#V518NB#15) is what I want to achieve(even one hole is enough). However the code in the link is using Babylon and I need it to be in ThreeJS. Any idea how I can use ThreeJS to achieve this(or to translate it to ThreeJS)?

**Update 1:**

There is a sample in ThreeJS examples ["misc_exporter_ply.html"](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_clipping_stencil.html)(it's got nothing to do with stencil buffer though) and so I tried to use it as it has a simple scene with only one box. I added another cylinder inside the box to represent the hole.

I could get it to work so that there is a visible hole. Yet it's not perfect as the stencil buffer is not working as expected:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH0lH.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64C3E.png)

And here is the code:

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - exporter - ply</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="info">
            <a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> webgl - exporter - ply<br/><br/>
            <button id="exportASCII">export ASCII</button> <button id="exportBinaryBigEndian">export binary (Big Endian)</button> <button id="exportBinaryLittleEndian">export binary (Little Endian)</button>
        </div>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

            import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { PLYExporter } from './jsm/exporters/PLYExporter.js';

            let scene, camera, renderer, exporter, mesh, meshHole, mesh0, mesh1;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.set( 200, 100, 200 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa1caf1 );
                //scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 200, 1000 );

                //exporter = new PLYExporter();

                //

                const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
                hemiLight.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
                scene.add( hemiLight );

                const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
                directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 180;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 100;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - 120;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 120;
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                // ground

                const ground = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xaaaaaa, depthWrite: false } ) );
                ground.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                ground.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( ground );

                const grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
                grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
                grid.material.transparent = true;
                scene.add( grid );

                //   mesh
 
                const boxHole = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 15, 65, 32, 32 );//BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 51 );  
                let matHole = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
                matHole.colorWrite = false;
                meshHole = new THREE.Mesh( boxHole, matHole ); 
                meshHole.castShadow = true;
                meshHole.position.y = 50; 
                meshHole.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                scene.add( meshHole );
                
                const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 ); 
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa }) );
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                mesh.position.y = 50; 
                scene.add( mesh );
                 
                // back faces
                const mat0 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
                mat0.side = THREE.FrontSide;
                mat0.depthWrite = false; 
                mat0.depthTest = false;
                mat0.colorWrite = false;
                //mat0.stencilWrite = true;
                mat0.stencilFunc = THREE.AlwaysStencilFunc;
                mat0.stencilFail = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
                //mat0.stencilZFail = THREE.IncrementWrapStencilOp;
                //mat0.stencilZPass = THREE.ReplaceStencilOp;  
                mat0.stencilRef = 1;
                const boxHole0 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 15, 65, 32, 32 );
                mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh( boxHole0, mat0 );
                mesh0.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                mesh0.castShadow = true;
                mesh0.position.y = 50;  
                scene.add( mesh0 );
                 
                // front faces
                const mat1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
                mat1.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                //mat1.depthWrite = false; 
                //mat1.depthTest = true;
                //mat1.colorWrite = false;
                //mat1.stencilWrite = true; 
                mat1.depthFunc=THREE.AlwaysDepth;
                mat1.stencilFunc = THREE.EqualStencilFunc;
                mat1.stencilFail = THREE.IncrementStencilOp;
                //mat1.stencilZFail = THREE.DecrementWrapStencilOp;
                //mat1.stencilZPass = THREE.DecrementWrapStencilOp; 
                mat1.stencilRef = 1;
                const boxHole1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 15, 65, 32, 32, true );
                mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( boxHole1, mat1 ); 
                mesh1.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                mesh1.castShadow = true;
                mesh1.position.z = 0;
                mesh1.position.y = 50;  
                scene.add( mesh1 );
     
                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.target.set( 0, 25, 0 );
                controls.update();

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
 
            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }
 
            const link = document.createElement( 'a' );
            link.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild( link );

             

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link I sent doesn't use any boolean operations. It's done purely using stencil buffer.

Comment: Indeed, I was tricked by the holes appearing to have proper normals! The calls used in the example are simple 1 to 1 WebGL mappings so it shouldn't be too hard to replicate this without babylon.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I have updated the question with my attempt on this using webgl but no luck so far. Would you mind have a look on this please?

Comment: Didn't you say you wanted plain webgl? So what does "no luck so far" mean?

Comment: Oops my apology. I am a bit new to webgl and ThreeJS. I meant translating it to ThreeJS. I updated the question. The pasted code in the question is my attempt which fails to create the hole.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "Constructive Solid Geometry", which works like a boolean operator for geometry. [Here's a library that does what you're looking for](https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh), where you can "subtract" a cylinder from a box. However, it requires you use an older version of Three.js `r124` or lower, because `r125+` no longer supports legacy `Geometry` formats.

Comment: @Marquizzo, I am aware of CSG library, but in this particular example I want to achieve same using stencil buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working at the end:

[Box with cylinder hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDo0C.png)

```js
            import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

            import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { PLYExporter } from './jsm/exporters/PLYExporter.js';

            let scene, camera, renderer, exporter, mesh, meshHole, mesh0, mesh1;

 

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.set( 200, 100, 200 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa1caf1 );
                //scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 200, 1000 );

                //exporter = new PLYExporter();

                //

                const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
                hemiLight.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
                scene.add( hemiLight );

                const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
                directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 180;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 100;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - 120;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 120;
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                // ground

                const ground = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xaaaaaa, depthWrite: false } ) );
                ground.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                ground.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( ground );

                const grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
                grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
                grid.material.transparent = true;
                scene.add( grid );

                //   mesh
 
                const boxHole = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 15, 51, 32, 32 );//BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 51 );  
                let matHole = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa });
                matHole.colorWrite = false;
                meshHole = new THREE.Mesh( boxHole, matHole ); 
                meshHole.castShadow = true;
                meshHole.position.y = 50; 
                meshHole.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                scene.add( meshHole );
                
                const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 ); 
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa }) );
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                mesh.position.y = 50; 
                scene.add( mesh );
                 
                // front faces
                const mat0 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa });
                mat0.side = THREE.FrontSide;
                //mat0.depthWrite = false; 
                //mat0.depthTest = false;
                mat0.colorWrite = false;
                const boxHole0 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 15, 51, 32, 32 );
                mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh( boxHole0, mat0 );
                mesh0.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                mesh0.castShadow = true;
                mesh0.position.y = 50;  
                scene.add( mesh0 );
                mat0.stencilWrite = true;
                mat0.stencilFunc = THREE.AlwaysStencilFunc;
                mat0.stencilFail = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
                mat0.stencilZFail = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
                mat0.stencilZPass = THREE.ReplaceStencilOp;
                mat0.stencilRef = 1;
                
                // back faces
                const mat1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa });
                mat1.side = THREE.BackSide;
                mat1.depthWrite = false; 
                mat1.depthTest = true;
                //mat1.colorWrite = false;
                const boxHole1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 15, 51, 32, 32, true );
                mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( boxHole1, mat1 ); 
                mesh1.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                mesh1.castShadow = true;
                mesh1.position.z = 0;
                mesh1.position.y = 50;  
                scene.add( mesh1 );
                mat1.depthFunc=THREE.AlwaysDepth;
                mat1.stencilWrite = true; 
                mat1.stencilFunc = THREE.EqualStencilFunc;
                mat1.stencilFail = THREE.DecrementWrapStencilOp;
                mat1.stencilZFail = THREE.DecrementWrapStencilOp;
                mat1.stencilZPass = THREE.DecrementWrapStencilOp;
                mat1.stencilRef = 1;
    
                mesh1.onAfterRender = function ( renderer ) {
                    renderer.clearStencil();
                };
                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.target.set( 0, 25, 0 );
                controls.update();

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
 
            }
```

[image: Screenshot]